# Regex findall start() and end() ? Python

Tags: python, regex, sequence, findall

i'm trying to get the start and end positions of a query in sequence by using re.findall

```
import re

sequence = 'aaabbbaaacccdddeeefff'

query = 'aaa'

findall = re.findall(query,sequence)

>>> ['aaa','aaa']
```

how do i get something like findall.start() or findall.end() ?

i would like to get

```
start = [0,6]
end = [2,8]
```

i know that

```
search = re.search(query,sequence)

print search.start(),search.end()

>>> 0,2
```

would give me only the first instance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> import re
>>> sequence = 'aaabbbaaacccdddeeefff'
>>> query = 'aaa'
>>> r = re.compile(query)
>>> [[m.start(),m.end()] for m in r.finditer(sequence)]
[[0, 3], [6, 9]]
```

From the docs:

> Return an `iterator` yielding `MatchObject` instances over all
>   non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.

Comment: Instead of `[m.start(), m.end()]` you can also just use `m.span()` which returns a tuple of the start and end indicies.

Comment: your code fails for -> sequence = 'aaadaa' query = 'aa' , Yours output (0, 2)
(4, 6) , Correct output (0, 1) (1, 2) (4, 5)

Comment: @SanjitPrasad It says clearly in the quoted text: "all non-overlapping matches..."

Comment: ooh sorry for that, what if we need to find overlapping matches too.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. `findall` is a convenience function that, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) say, returns "a list of strings". If you want a list of `MatchObject`s, you can't use `findall`.

However, you *can* use `finditer`. If you're just iterating over the matches `for match in re.findall(…):`, you can use `for match in re.finditer(…)` the same way—except you get `MatchObject` values instead of strings. If you actually need a list, just use `matches = list(re.finditer(…))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use finditer instead of findall. This gives you back an iterator yielding MatchObject instances and you can get start/end from the MatchObject.